# yii2 mysql count query

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

i'm struggle with show the data

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ErformSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $erform = Erform::find()->all();


   return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'erform'=>$erform,
    ]);
}
```

then in my view site

```
foreach ($erform as $erform) {
    echo $erform->event_type;
}
```

and the result is all the event type, now i wanna count my event type and show the numbers of counts

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to count total $`dataProvider` records

```
$dataProvider->getTotalCount();
```

Count records for particular page

```
$dataProvider->getCount();
```

Count Records in variable

```
count($variable_name)
```

Update :

```
$erform = Erform::find()->where(['user_type'=>'a'])->all();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but if i wanna count specific value from fields, can you teach me how from $dataProvider?

Comment: Can you pls explain more

Comment: >$dataProvider -> getTotalCount();

i get all the records, how to use Count Records in variable?

Comment: count($variable_name)

Comment: Or if you want to count string than use : strlen($variable_name)

Comment: Sorry again, i'm use count($variable_name) and i get the records of the table,

but i have fields of event_type
eg.
Table erform
Fields event_type
2 records of event A
4 records of event B
6 records of event C

If i use count($erform) it will show 12, if i wanna show 2 (event a) only?

Thank You

Comment: Thank You Mr Yasin Patel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` function, i.e.:

```
$count = count ($erform);
foreach ($erform as $erform) {
    echo $erform->event_type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 you can get directly from dataProvider.If you need the total count of the rows selected  you can use:

```
<php
  echo $dataProvider->getTotalCount();
?>
```